# Uploading an image to a boto bucket

Tags: django, amazon-s3, boto, boto3

I am trying to an upload that I am retrieving from django forms to the amazon boto. But everytime I save it gets saved in first_part/second_part/third_part/amazon-sw/(required image) instead of getting saved in first_part/second_part/third_part.

I use the tinys3 library. I tried but found boto to be a little complex to use so used tinys3. Please do help me out.

```
        access_key = aws_details.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
        secret_key = aws_details.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
        bucket_name = "s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/first_part/second_part/third_part/"
        myfile = request.FILES['image'] # getting the image from html view
        fs = FileSystemStorage() 
        fs.save('demo_blah_blah.png', myfile) # saving the image
        conn = tinys3.Connection(access_key, secret_key, tls=True, endpoint='s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com') # connecting to the bucket
        f = open('demo_blah_blah.png', 'rb')
        conn.upload('test_pic10000.png', f, bucket_name) # uploading to boto using tinys3 library
```

Comment: Not to get into an opinion-based discussion, but maybe check out django-storages: https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

It'll integrate with Django's pluggable storage system, so you can just use a standard `models.FileField`  or `models.ImageField` and it'll 'automatically' get saved to S3.